# AC wire hanging out by itself in receptacle, safe?

Tags: electrical

I am replacing my smoke detector with a Nest one (battery powered) and no longer need this AC connection -- is it okay to tuck it into the wall as it is or should there be a cap or something? Not sure how safe or unsafe either route is (and whether a cap exists here to place on the plug). Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is this in a single-family house, or an apartment building?

Answer (score 2):

To your question on the plugs, yes you can just stuff them into the hole and leave them there, there are no exposed wires (no more than any switch or receptacle would have anyway). If you are overly cautious you could put some electrical tape over them, but I didn't bother when I swapped mine out.

One thing to be aware of, many of these older "hard wired" smoke detectors would "talk" to other units on the same wires, so if one goes off, they all go off, but also they would learn what other units were on the connections. So when you remove only one of them then, you get the others eventually start "chirping" at you to tell you that one of their pals is not responding. So if you remove one, you should remove and replace them all.

Also, some local fire codes REQUIRE that you have hard wired smoke detectors with battery backup. While living in the house it's up to you, but when you go to sell the house some day (or you are a renter and move out), you may be required to replace them with hard wired versions again.

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't a cap to fit over the plug. If you gently pull the plug out of the box you'll see some wire nuts that you can just unscrew, remove the plug wire and then screw back up. Be careful not to disconnect any of the other wires. Remember to turn off the power when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that!

You currently have a hardwired smoke detector system that connects to other smoke detectors in the unit, and possibly in the rest of the building, and possibly to alarms.

That type of hardwired smoke detector system system is generally **required by Code**.  You're not allowed to tear them all out, and stick in a couple of common $20 solitary bolt-up smoke detectors.

Further, you can't do that *even if the $20 solitary costs $200*.   There are two aspects to this:

### Mains power

A hardwired detector means you don't need to change batteries.  That's a Code requirement for a couple of reasons.  First, people aren't good at changing batteries.  Second, available power means the ability to use sensing methods that require more power.  You mustn't downgrade except with fire marshal approval.

### Interconnection

Sure, Nest does some neat thing with interconnecting **your Nests**.  But what it cannot do is interconnect with a "burglar alarm" type system, or in a multi-unit structure, the building's master fire alarm so the alarm can be sounded in other units.   Again, the Nest functionality needs to fully replace what the wired system is doing now, and it doesn't (unless engineering confirms that it does).  So again, this type of system change needs fire marshal approval.

The other question that needs to be examined is if Nests can do their "intercommunication-among-Nests" job if the WIFi is down.  Because WiFi goes down, especially if the fire starts in the electrical service to the WiFi equipment.

Comment: Funny how you say: A hardwired smoke detector means you dont need to change the batteries, that's false... My house has hardwired smoke detectors also and if I dont change the batteries every 2 or 3 years I start hearing chirp.......chirp........chirp lol the good thing about these hardwired ones is that they dont just detect smoke, any combustible fumes also set them off

Comment: Not all hard-wired detectors are interconnected, either to other detectors or a central system. Current code in my area requires hard-wire with battery back-up, but no requirement for inter-connectivity.